# Build a sequence from a function

Tags: ocaml

I wrote these function to build a sequence from a function i am having a stack overflow error while testing it

```
let rec from_fun f ()=
  match f () with
  | None -> Nil
  | Some e -> Cons(e, from_fun f)
from_fun (fun () -> let x = 0 in if x<10 then Some (x+1) else None)
```

thanks

Comment: How you test your function? Obviously the code you provided can't produce stack overflow just because there is no any function call. And in general as far as I understand you try to encode infinite sequence, so the only way to get stack overflow is to inspect all your sequence (which is infinite), but logically you don't need to do this, so I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of a generator:

```
let range_generator from below step =
  let counter = ref from
  in fun () ->
       if (!counter < below)
       then (let result = (Some !counter) in
             counter := !counter + step;
             result)
       else None
```

For example, a call to `range_generator 0 10 2` returns a closure over an internal `counter` mutable variable which generates all natural even numbers below 10:

```
# let gen = range_generator 0 10 2;;
val gen : unit -> int option = <fun>
```

Each call to `gen` possibly mutates the internal counter:

```
# gen();;
- : int option = Some 0
# gen();;
- : int option = Some 2
# gen();;
- : int option = Some 4
# gen();;
- : int option = Some 6
# gen();;
- : int option = Some 8
# gen();;
- : int option = None
# gen();;
- : int option = None
```

With your function:

```
# from_fun (range_generator 0 5 1);;
- : int list = [0; 1; 2; 3; 4]
```

Answer (score 4):

Your function always returns `Some 1`. It never returns `None`. So the sequence is infinitely long and the stack overflows while building it.

If you want a function to return different values when you call it, you can do two things. First, you can pass it different parameters. This isn't possible for your design of `from_fun`--the parameter to the function is always `()`.  Second, your function can be impure. I.e., the function can maintain some mutable state.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `x` you are using is local to the anonymous function you are using. As a result the function always return `Some 1`.
What you probably wanted to do is for the function to take an argument:

```
let rec from_fun f n =
    match f n with
    | None -> Nil
    | Some e -> Cons(e, from_fun f e)

let seq = from_fun (fun x -> if x<10 then Some (x+1) else None) 0
```

EDIT:
Here is a solution with the appropriate type signature:

```
let rec from_fun f () =
    match f () with
    | None -> Nil
    | Some e -> Cons(e, from_fun f ())

let x = ref 0

let seq = from_fun
    (fun () ->
        let v = !x in
        if v < 10
        then begin
            x := v + 1;
            Some v
        end
        else None)
    ()
```

It is worth noting that because of the side effects, you would have to reinitialise `x` before building a new sequence. The `unit` argument passed in parameter to `from_fun` is unnecessary, you could remove it.